# When destination bit is F does the working register change? (PIC16F Assembly)

Tags: assembly, pic

As far as I know all the operations are done through the working register in PIC16F. In datasheet, it says when the destination bit is W, the result is written into working register, when it is F, the result is written into the file register. What I'm asking is that, when the destination bit is F does the working register change since the operation is done through it? Or does it stay unaffected?

For example;

Assume W = 3, temp = 5, temp2 = 10

```
INCF temp,F
DECF temp2,F
```

What are the contents after these instructions?

Answer (score 0):

When the destination bit of some instruction is F or 1 the working register W (WREG) never change!
After execution of instruction:

```
INCF temp,F
```

...the content of `temp` register is incremented for 1.
In case:

```
INCF temp,W
```

the content of `temp` register remain unchanged and result `temp + 1` is stored in WREG.

**You can use MPLAB simuator as part of MPLAB IDE to test any part of your asm code.**

Comment: I know that I can use the simulator but I wanted to learn if it's not affected why and how? Since the ALU works on WREG should not it change?

Comment: That is a feature of PIC16 RISC memonic. The `WREG` is one of two possibilites were the MCPUs ALU store the result. In case of `incf` instruction the 8th bit of 14bit long instruction is `d` or destination bit. If this bit is 0 then result of instruction is stored in WREG, if `d` bit is 1 then result is stored back to the file register.